# Resetting the value of fields after submitting the ruby form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have search field based on date entered.

The problem is whenever I am submitting the form then searched results comes good but search string disappears from the field as the page reloaded.

Can anyone tell me how to persist the search string in the field.

I am using ruby form and below is the code..

```
<%=form_for :messages, url: url_for( :controller => :time_sheets, :action => :late ), :html => { :id => "submitForm1" } do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
             <tr>   
                <td> From Date <%= f.text_field :leaveFrom, :id => 'datepicker2', :class => 'phcolor','data-validation' =>'required', :readonly => true %></td>
                <td> To Date <%= f.text_field :leaveTo, :id => 'datepicker7', :class => 'phcolor', :readonly => true %></td>
                <td >Late Time<%= f.text_field :on_duty, :id => 'timepicker5' %></td>
                <div class="actions">
                  <td style="position: absolute;right: 178px;"><input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="submitid" tabindex="7" value="Go"></td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `form_for :messages` suggests that there is an instance variable `@messages`, which holds the data of the fields in the form. Is there a valid `@messages`?

If you don't have Model for messages, I think of a simple workaround. You can add this to the action:

```
@messages = OpenStruct.new(params[:messages])
```

Or, just replace `form_for` with `form_tag`, and set value of each fields from params. `form_for` "creates a form and a scope around a specific model object that is used as a base for questioning about values for the fields.", which is not suitable here.

Comment: No. i do't need any instance in the controller ...so that is not valid message i am taking data from database and rendering back on view page .. i am not able to persist data in may date field after submitting the form .. because page is getting refreshed ..is there any way to persist it ..

Answer (score 1):

If your form isn't related to any model then use the `form_tag` helpers etc. Then you would do something like:

```
<%= text_field_tag :leaveFrom, params[:leaveFrom], :id => 'datepicker2', :class => 'phcolor','data-validation' =>'required', :readonly => true %>
```